# Kirouv and hassidic dynasty

Tags: chasidut-hasidism, organizations, kiruv-outreach

Besides Chabad, which hassidic dynasty has a french or english speaking outreach (kirouv) program ?

I know Belz has one, but I cannot find more information about it online. I also heard that Satmar has one for french people but I am not sure.

Answer (score 3):

Several Breslov (aka Breslev) groups are active in kiruv in the US. Breslov is the one branch of chassidus that never had a dynasty. Rebbe Nachman of Breslov did not believe in hereditary dynasties of rebbes. Instead, there has been a small group of Breslov gedolim in each generation.

One particularly active and prolific Breslov kiruv group is run by Israeli Rabbi Shalom Arush, and his charismatic English-speaking spokesperson Rabbi Lazer Brody. Their organization runs the website Breslev Israel (http://www.breslev.co.il), which is translated into several languages, including French and English, and a ba'al teshuvah-oriented yeshivah in Yerushalayim, Chut Shel Chessed. They have published numerous books and CDs, and Rabbi Brody frequently goes on speaking tours around Israel and in the US.

Rabbi Avraham ben Yaakov runs http://www.azamra.org, which provides translations of many Breslov works, including original texts by Rabbe Nachman, as well as his own books.

Rabbi Dovid Sears (who has also written several interesting books) runs a Breslov outreach organization called the Breslov Center (http://breslovcenter.blogspot.com/).

Comment: I read in Mishapacha magazine that R Arush says that he is the lowliest of the low. Being a BT, Moroccan sefardi, and Breslav chosid. Therefore like har sinai the shechina rests on him. I can understand why a BT is low. But why are the Morroccan sefardim the lowest grade of sefardim and the Breslov the lowest grade of chasidim. Will perhaps answer shortly.

Comment: Thank you very much! I heard that Satmar also offers this kind of program, maybe you could tell me more about this.

Comment: Annex, I don't know why he said that about the Moroccans; perhaps they are seen as lower class. As for Breslov, he's probably referring to the fact that people sometimes look down on Breslov chassidus and associated it with crazy people. I think this is mainly because of the Na-Nachs, a splinter group which comprises a very small percentage of Breslov chassidim, but which is the most visible, with all their ebullient dancing in the streets in Israel.

Comment: Far22, I don't know much more than what I said. I recommend reading the websites I mentioned above, especially Breslev Israel, and checking out the French section of their bookstore: http://www.breslev.co.il/store/books/breslev_books_french.aspx?category=296&pageid=1&language=english

Comment: There also seem to be some other Breslov websites in French (such as http://www.breslev.fr/, and the other ones listed here: http://www.breslov.com/content.html), though as a non-French speaker I don't know whether this means there is a Breslov kiruv program in France or other Francophone countries.

Comment: Far22, if you're interested in learning more about Breslov kiruv programs, I also recommend reading Rabbi Lazer Brody's English blog (http://lazerbrody.typepad.com/), and emailing him if you have any questions. He always answers emails.

Comment: Thank you very much. Besides the breslov, do you know another community who do kiruv?